# How do I tell Make to ignore files which haven't been updated?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am new to using Make and I am having some trouble figuring out the syntax. I went through a few examples and I essentially combined a few of them to create my own file. I am not sure how to tell make to ignore already compiled source or header files that haven't changed. How can I get make to compile only the files that have changed?

I looked on the GNU website: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Avoiding-Compilation.html

I tried some of those flags, but I still am not getting the results I wanted.

```
# specify compiler
CC=gcc
# set compiler flags
CFLAGS=-Igen/display -Igen/logic -Iman -Ilib/include -pipe -march=native
# set linker flags
LDFLAGS=-lglut32 -loglx -lopengl32 -Llib 
# include all sources
SOURCES=gen/display/*.c gen/logic/*.c man/*.c
# create objects from the source files
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
# specify the name and the output directory of executable
EXECUTABLE=win32/demo

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

# compile the target file from sources 
# $@ = placeholder for target name
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

I have a number of header and source files in different directories that are being compiled, but no matter what I do everything recompiles.

Comment: How about `OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)` ?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you don't need to make `all` depend on `$(SOURCES)`.

Comment: `make` does that automatically.

Comment: You would probably be better off with the built-in `.c.o` rule than with providing your own.  If you *do* provide your own, however, then get it right: to compile to an object file but avoid linking (at that time) into a program, you need the `-c` flag -- `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<`.  But again, `make` has a built-in `.c.o` rule that will do the right thing here, and you are needlessly overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's do it, as it ought to be done ;-)

```
# set up our variables
# note: you may also prefer := or ?= assignments,
#       however it's not that important here
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Igen/display -Igen/logic -Iman -Ilib/include -pipe -march=native
# linker's flags are different from compiler's
LDFLAGS=
# these are really libs, not flags
LDLIBS=-Llib -lglut32 -loglx -lopengl32

# 1) make is not your shell - it does not expand wildcards by default
# 2) use := to force immediate wildcard expansion;
#    otherwise make could perform it several times,
#    which is, at the least, very ineffective
SOURCES:=$(wildcard gen/display/*.c gen/logic/*.c man/*.c)

# use the right extensions here: .c -> .o
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

# note: it's okay to omit .exe extension if you're using "POSIX"-like make
# (e.g. cygwin/make or msys/make). However, if your make was built on Windows
# natively (such as mingw32-make), you'd better to add '.exe' here
EXECUTABLE=win32/demo

# don't forget to say to make that 'all' is not a real file
.PHONY: all
# *.c files are what you write, not make
# note: in fact, you don't need 'all' target at all;
#       this is rather a common convention
all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

# note: 1) suffix rules are deprecated; use pattern rules instead
#       2) this doesn't add much to the built-in rule, so you can even omit it
#       3) .o files are created in the same directories where .c files reside;
#          most of the time this is not the best solution, although it's not
#          a mistake per se
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks man! I appreciate you taking the time to explain everything and correct my code. It works great!!